# Proving that something cannot be a coordinate ring of an affine variety

Tags: ring-theory

This was the problem that was given: Let $k$ be a field and define 
$R = \frac{k[x, y]} {< x^2 >}$ Prove that R cannot be the coordinate ring of a variety $V \subseteq A^2_k$.

I'm confused about what the question is actually asking. I know that a coordinate ring of a variety is of the form: $\frac{k[x_1,x_2...x_n]}{I(V)}$. However, I don't really understand that $R$ cannot be a coordinate ring in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coordinate ring is always a reduced ring, because $I(V)$ is necessarily radical. On the other hand $k[x,y]/(x^2)$ has some obvious nonzero nilpotent elements.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by a reduce ring and what you mean by nonzero nilpotent elements?

Comment: The terminology is standard, both in English books an on English internet, as far as I know.

Comment: You're right - I double checked my notes and found it, thank you. So would I be correct in saying that in this case we have to prove that $R$ cannot be a reduced ring, and therefore must find a non-zero nilpotent element? In that case, don't we know it cannot be a reduced  ring because if $x = 0$ then $x^2 = 0$ and therefore it is nilpotent?

Comment: That was the point.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: I actually looked back and thought more about the problem. To show that $R$ cannot be a reduced ring, we have to find a NON-zero nilpotent element. So my idea of using $x = 0$ would not work, so I'm a little confused on how to show that $R$ is not a reduced ring

Comment: Try with the nilpotent element $xy^5+9x\in R$